# I tried many GSM modules with RPI 3B+ but no response

Tags: python, pi-3b+

I used both of adafruit fona gsm module and sim900 chip but when i want to see the response by sending AT, i got nothing even though i am sure of my connection is right. I have heard i cant use ttyAMA0 because of the Bluetooth thing, any suggestions please

I tried both of socat and screen. The ttyAMA0 port is not responding so then is used socat - /dev/serial0 and it was working but when i have tried it again when i enter AT i receive OK infinitely i dont know what is the reason and for the screen i tried screen - /dev/ttyAMA0 115200 and screen - /dev/serial0 115200, and no response I tried to change the baud rate but still no response

[image]

And here what chip i am using

[image]

I followed the same tutorial provided by their website but some of the commands now working because i am using different raspberry pi i am using the latest version

https://learn.adafruit.com/fona-tethering-to-raspberry-pi-or-beaglebone-black/setup

I have heard that i need to manipulate with the bluetooth configuration since it is now using the port/dev/ttyAMA0

Comment: So which port did you use? With current kernel/firmware you should use `/dev/serial0`. You added the `python` label, but did you try to connect with a standard comms program (minicom, picocom or any other)? Are you sure you used the correct communication settings for your module? Please update your question with relevant information.

Comment: Check please my edit

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what do you mean by the latest version? If it is RPI 3B+ then you should try connecting with `/ttyS0`. RPI 2 uses `/ttyAMA0`.
Also, you said SIM900 but the picture and the documentation is for SIM800.

Check this 
[link](http://www.python-exemplary.com/index_en.php?inhalt_links=navigation_en.inc.php&inhalt_mitte=raspi/en/gsm.inc.php)
to understand what you should do. It helped me ones when I was dealing with SIM900. Also, make sure you opened the serial interface from the settings. [This](https://sixfab.com/updated-tutorial-2-make-a-ppp-internet-connection-with-sixfab-gprs-shield-on-raspberry-pi/) might help with that.

If you have further questions please give the correct versions of the development boards.